# 'and' operator in string.contains

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I have a pandas series in which I am applying string search this way

```
df['column_name'].str.contains('test1')
```

This gives me true/false list depending on string 'test1' is contained in column 'column_name' or not.

However I am not able to test two strings where I need to check if both strings are there or not. Something like

```
  df['column_name'].str.contains('test1' and 'test2')
```

This does not seem to work. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you have to create 2 conditions and use `&` and wrap parentheses around the conditions due to operator precedence:

```
(df['column_name'].str.contains('test1')) & (df['column_name'].str.contains('test2))
```

If you wanted to test for either word then the following would work:

```
df['column_name'].str.contains('test1|test2')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
all( word in df['column_name'] for word in ['test1', 'test2'] )
```

this will test an arbitrary number or words present in a string

Comment: You can change your list comprehension to a more efficient generator by removing the outermost square brackets. Then a new list won't be created and `all` will be able to short-circuit.

Comment: 'all' is giving me a single true/false value. I need for every entry in the colubomn, whether both test1 and test2 exist. So if column_name is 400 long, I want to know how many of them has 'test1' and how many of them as 'test2'. EdChums's answer so far makes most sense

Comment: your question stated that you need to check for both, i assumed you wanted to do it simultaneously because you used the `and` operator instead of `or`

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the missing quote from `'test2`, the 'and' operator is a boolean logical operator. It does not concatenate strings and it does not perform the action that you are thinking it does.

```
>>> 'test1' and 'test2'
'test2'
>>> 'test1' or 'test2'
'test1'
>>> 10 and 20
20
>>> 10 and 0
10
>>> 0 or 20
20
>>> # => and so on...
```

This occurs because the `and` and `or` operators function as 'truth deciders' and have mildly strange behavior with strings. In essence, the return value is the last value to have been evaluated, whether it's a string or otherwise. Look at this behavior:

```
>>> a = 'test1'
>>> b = 'test2'
>>> c = a and b
>>> c is a
False
>>> c is b
True
```

The latter value is assigned to the variable to which we are giving it. What you're looking for is a way to iterate over a list or set of strings and ensure that all of them result in true. We use the `all(iterable)` function for this.

```
if all([df['column_name'].contains(_) for _ in ['test1', 'test2']]):
    print("All strings are contained in it.")
else:
    print("Not all strings are contained in it.")
```

Assuming the case is true, the following is an example of what you'd receive:

```
>>> x = [_ in df['column_name'] for _ in ['test1', 'test2']
>>> print(x)
[True, True] # => returns True for all()
>>> all(x)
True
>>> x[0] = 'ThisIsNotIntTheColumn' in df['column_name']
>>> print(x)
[False, True]
>>> all(x)
False
```

Comment: Thanks added the missing quote in 'test2'

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I got to learn quite a few things in this but not sure if I can directly use any of it for achieving what I want to achieve

Comment: Take a look at the third code segment. That should perform what you want it to perform.

Comment: Thanks goodies. How do I get a count of number of match and number of misses in column_name entries. I use vale_counts() command on EdChums solution and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know if `test1` AND `test2` are somewhere in the column.

So `df['col_name'].str.contains('test1').any() & df['col_name'].str.contains('test2').any()`.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to any(), however in this requirement, I need to know how many entries in column_name there is a match and in how many there is not

Answer (score 0):

Just use reduce() method if you need to apply a list of strings as a filter

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_name': [1,'test1_sdv_test2_vsd',3,4,5, 'test2test1'],
    'column_name_2': [3,6,3,2,7,8]
})

items = ['test1', 'test2'] # list of strings you want to apply as filter


def filter_series_by_list(s, items): 
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a & b, (s.str.contains(item, na=False) for item in items))


print(filter_series_by_list(df['column_name'], items))


RESULT:
0    False
1    True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    True
Name: column_name, dtype: bool
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).